# How to assign the ResourceDictionary string as switch case Constant Expression?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

```
switch ("Case2")
        {
            case (string)Application.Current.FindResource("Case1");
                //Do Some logic
                break;
            case (string)Application.Current.FindResource("Case2");
                //Do Some logic
                break;
            case (string)Application.Current.FindResource("Case3");
                //Do Some logic
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

I did this code But it is not work. Now i want to assign the string value(**(string)Application.Current.FindResource("Case1")**) which getting from resource dictionary to constant expression.How is it possible or else is there any way ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible.  A [constant expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691319%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is, by definition, a *compile*-time constant.  A resource dictionary lookup must happen at *run* time.  The usual solution is to use a string of `if` statements:

```
if ("Case2" == (string)Application.Current.FindResource("Case1"))
{
    //Do some logic
}
else if ("Case2" == (string)Application.Current.FindResource("Case2"))
{
    //Do some logic
}
else if ("Case2" == (string)Application.Current.FindResource("Case3"))
{
    //Do some logic
}
```